# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - Java Error

Tags: java, exception, user-interface, program-entry-point, graphics2d

When I Run My Code, I Get this Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at Main.drawBlock(Main.java:48)
at Main.<init>(Main.java:43)
at Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

I Think this is Because of The Graphics that I Drew, But That Never Happened Before.
I Have No Idea WHY. Here is My Code:

```
Graphics2D g;
static JFrame jf = new JFrame();
Image Air;
Image Grass;
Image icon;

public Main() {
    icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Icon.png")).getImage();
    Grass = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Grass.png")).getImage();
    Air = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Air.png")).getImage();

    jf.setIconImage(icon);
    drawBlock(Air,0,0);

}

private void drawBlock(Image img, int x, int y) {
    g.drawImage(img,x,y,null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    jf.setSize(792,528);
    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setTitle("Minecraft 2D Adventure");

    new Main();


}}
```

Comment: If you use a `Graphics` object anywhere except in `paint*` (or a method called from there), chances are that you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You don't assign anything to `Graphics2D g`, hence the NPE.

See AmitD's answer for a more detailed analysis of the issue and pointers how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not initialized `Graphics2D g` so g is `null`

The real Reason of `NPE` is `Graphics2D` is a `AbstractClass` and you can not instantiate it.

You can create instance of `Graphics2D` instance like below

```
GraphicsEnvironment env =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
 env.createGraphics(BufferedImage);
```

or you can use `createGraphics()` From `BufferedImage`

```
public Graphics2D createGraphics()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't assign a value to an allocated object, it's default value is `null`. So you are referring back to nothing when you reference `g`.